# Is hosted workbench officially run / supported by Salesforce?

Tags: api, data, support

Is workbench officially run / supported by Salesforce?

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Workbench

1. If I am executing queries and downloading data using the bulk api, is that data stored on the workbench hosted platform before being downloaded or is it simply parsing the file to the local machine directly from Salesforce without being stored in the middle.
2. Similarly if I am uploading files for ad-hoc bulk processing, is this data stored on the workbench hosted platform before being submitted to Salesforce for processing.

Answer (score 12):

Workbench does not have its own database, so nothing is stored long term. The only storage Workbench has is a Redis cluster used for short-term session management and background process queuing. Individual users' settings are stores in browser cookies. So, to answer your questions specifically:

1. Bulk CSV/XML queries and their results are not stored in Workbench at all. All processing is done on the SFDC side and Workbench is just proxying the data.
2. Uploaded files are stored temporarily for the life of the transaction and then destroyed.

Comment: The gods walk among us! ;-)

Comment: Indeed. This is great exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think so. When you read the terms and agreements as of today it says:

5.No Warranty. WORKBENCH IS PROVIDED "AS-IS," EXCLUSIVE OF ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER. SFDC DISCLAIMS ALL EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION ANY IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. WORKBENCH IS NOT A PRODUCT OF SFDC AND IS NOT SUPPORTED BY SFDC IN ANY WAY. Workbench may contain bugs or errors. Any production use of Workbench is at Your sole risk. You acknowledge that SFDC may discontinue making Workbench available to You at any time in its sole discretion.

But I use workbench (Rest explorer) console pretty much every day when I play around with REST API code

Comment: Devil is in the detail - thanks for highlighting...

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, '[hosted Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/)' is officially run by salesforce.com, but, as [rao](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/582/rao) points out in [his answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1736/67), it is not officially supported. I'll ping [ryanbrainard](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/187/ryanbrainard), author of Workbench, to answer your two sub-questions.

Comment: So officially run by Salesforce.com means it's in their data centre somewhere?

Comment: It's actually on Heroku, which, in turn, is on AWS:  
`ppatterson-ltm:MyHybridApp ppatterson$ host workbench.developerforce.com  
workbench.developerforce.com is an alias for miyagi-7985.herokussl.com.  
miyagi-7985.herokussl.com is an alias for elb002677-882853899.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.  
elb002677-882853899.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 107.20.201.82  
elb002677-882853899.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 174.129.237.142  
elb002677-882853899.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 107.21.117.230`

Comment: @MichaelGill I can't seem to put line breaks in a comment, but hopefully, it's clear!

Comment: Yep that's cool